# How to best present a PhD application when moving from professional work without a masters or honours degree?

Tags: phd, application, funding, australia

I have been invited by a potential supervisor to apply for a PhD scholarship based on some research I have done in a professional role. I have a history of presenting this kind of work at mixed academic/professional conferences in the past, and have written some of my research up for professional associations and as whitepapers.

In my opinion, the work that I have done may well revolutionise my particular field and there is a lot of interesting applications I have been able to articulate, but I feel having it as part of a doctoral thesis will help push these ideas into the mainstream.

However, I am concerned, as when I did my Bachelors degree I kind of messed around for my first few years and haven't got a strong background in actual academia. While I did clean up my act and finished with a high enough average grade to continue onto an honours year, I chose to work instead.

The application says:

> Minimum admission requirements to the PhD program at [University name redacted]: a relevant Bachelors degree with at least upper second-class honours, or a Masters degree with a significant research component, or equivalent.

Given my ordinary academic history, how can I best demonstrate my ability to perform research and give the best chance to be successful?

Answer (score 1):

Your next step is quite clear. Discuss this with your potential supervisor. That person will be aware of university policies and practices, and could perhaps set up another meeting with the relevant staff.

Be proactive.